# How to maintain persistent count over multiple file executions

Tags: bash

In a bash script, how do you keep persistent variable values over multiple file executions?

I'm trying to keep track of how many times a certain line has executed over multiple sessions/executions of a script. Naturally, declaring the Count variable at the beginning of the script will reset it every time it runs

Comment: store the value in something more persistent, such as a file or a database.

Comment: Put it in another script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple example of maintaining persistent state for a `bash` script.

```
#!/bin/bash

read count < ~/.myscriptcount
(( count++ ))

# ...

echo "$count" > ~/.myscriptcount
```

Note that you'll probably want to ensure that `$count` is always written back to the desired value, even if your script crashes or exits early (using the `trap` command, likely). You'll also have to modify this if the script can be run concurrently with itself, to avoid the race condition on updating `.myscriptcount`.

Comment: how would you make sure the value is written with `trap`?

Comment: Something like `trap 'echo "$count" > ~/.myscriptcount' EXIT` might suffice.

Comment: A simple solution might  be to use `echo >>~/.myscriptlog` instead of incrementing the count, which atomically outputs one character for each execution. If you were expecting hundreds of millions of executions, you could periodically reduce the file to a count.

Comment: Then you need to read the entire file to get the most recent count, which could be slow.

Comment: @chepner: You just need to `stat` it.

Comment: Ah, you're using the file size (reflecting the number of newlines) as the implicit counter. Nice.